# html2canvas not working with @font-face font in chrome

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ for converting my html into canvas. it is a great script.
it works very well with english font.. .but i am working with gujrati font. i'm including font from css (@font-face)
it works well in firefox, but in chrome it does not show the exact character.
is there any options i missing in this code?

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  width: 300,
  height: 300
});
```

Comment: Could you setup an example on jsfiddle with the font in use, I could try and see if its a bug that could be fixed

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Google Fonts.

Comment: I know it's an old question but, did you find any answer ?

Comment: far as I'm concerned html2canvas is just broken if it cannot render fonts correctly.